# clFFT for visual studio, opencl

Tags: opencl, gpu

What is the best way to perform fft with opencl? (my gpu is intel HD graphics 4600)

I found clfft library, but stucked on installing it. I read documentation, but don't understand couple things. It requires some dependencies, one of them is AMD APP SDK, and as I can guess its only for amd gpu's? Can I use it with intel hd graphics?

Comment: If it is for OpenCL (and it is). Then it will work on and OpenCL enabled device. It asks for AMD APP SDK probably because it needs it just to build the CL dependancies.

Comment: Ok, thanks... and how install all that? I am so embarrassed with all this apk sdk, boost and other. I have never worked with source files earlier, so its a little bit confusing for me.